# c# login registration form registers user details only 1 time

Tags: c#, forms, registration

I've created a c# user registration form with md5 encryption... But my problem is I want to register a user detail under the "Admin level" at only one time..

What i want is when i seleet the admin level and try to re register as another user,the system might not give permission to register another admin..and shows a message box as "Sorry the admin has already registered in the system"...

my code is........

```
if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "" && comboBox1.Text != "" && (comboBox1.Text == "Administrator" || comboBox1.Text == "Employee" || comboBox1.Text == "Developer"))
        {

            connection.Open();
            string TypeUser;
            int level = Convert.ToInt32(0);

            TypeUser = comboBox1.Text;

            if (TypeUser == "Administrator")
            {
                level = 1;

            }
            else if (TypeUser == "Employee")
            {
                level = 2;

            }
            else if (TypeUser == "Developer")
            {
                level = 3;

            }


            MySqlDataReader dr;
            MySqlCommand cmd;
            string sql = "INSERT INTO users(name,password,level) VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "',MD5('" + textBox2.Text + "'),'" + level + "')";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            MessageBox.Show("Registration Success !","Success",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            connection.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("All Fields must be required / something is wrong", "error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if already is existing a record in the database with level equal to 1. You could write a method like this and you should call it before you are inserting the user.

```
public bool CheckForExistingAdmin(int level)
{
    if(level != 1)
       return false;

     int count = 0;

     using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection ("ConnectionString")
     {
         conn.Open();

         MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
         cmd.Connection = conn;
         cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT Count(ID) FROM Users WHERE Level = 1";

         count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

      }

      return count > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

After that in your code:

```
if(CheckForExistingAdmin)
{
    //show error message;
    return; //exit from the method;
}

MySqlDataReader dr;
MySqlCommand cmd;
//other stuff.
```

You have some essential problems with your code. First you are open to sql injection. You should use parameterized queries to be protected. Like I show in my example, also use **using** block or try/catch/finally when you write connection to db. It is possible a exception to occur and in this case your connection will stay open.

You can write separate module for connection to db too.